# Running 16-bit app on 64-bit is now possible? NTVDMx64

Tags: 64-bit, ms-dos, 16-bit, ntvdm

The program comes from Leecher1337, who created a `NTVDM for x64 bit`.

http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/ntvdmx64.html

https://github.com/leecher1337/ntvdmx64

I've tested on many Windows via VirtualBox, it worked half a time. (Worked on Windows 10 64 bits).
Running DOS Application worked, I've tested on `Foxpro 2.6 for DOS`.
I know that NTVDM is the composant used for `x32` to run 16-bit apps.

Here are my questions :

- Is that program trustable ? (I don't have knowledge to answer this)
- In terms of security, is there any problem? (If I want to setup this in Enterprise)
- Is it efficient for a production environment?

Comment: [Opinions don't fit Q&A format well](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). What question are you asking, exactly? You can [edit] your post to improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NTVDMx64 is referred by several sources as trustworthy, but this is finally your
decision to make.
You should know that it's very slow and uses non-standard methods of
loading programs.

You may also look at the following alternatives:

- [vDos](https://www.vdos.info/) (donationware)
  is better for most purposes
- [DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/) is also a worthy alternative.

Comment: Actually, I've tested these alternatives. I'm running a FoxPro 2.6 DOS version, through a telnet. I've tried to do this with Dosemu, or Dosbox, Wine... Running such an app is not a problem, but when you realize operations inside database (FoxPro), it takes 18 times more to do it through Emulation rather than running it directly.

Comment: My problem with a university-made product is that it may not be robust enough for a production environment, and no idea what kind of support you will get. I see you have also created a VM for Windows 32-bit (or even 16-bit). If VirtualBox has issues you could try VMware or Hyper-V, where you do have support and extensive user forums.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. That is what I wanted to know, I forgot to mention the production environment. Well, I met another problem. I tried to telnet the Windows 64 bit server (in which I installed Ntvdmx64), but it was impossible. "Program not compatible with Windows..."  (It maybe deserves a proper topic for this)
I tried with SSH, it opened it but with graphical defaults. I'll try working with VMware, thank you Harry.

Answer (score 1):

NTVDMx64 is fine. It does its work (loading 16bit programs) and nothing else. We can all agree it is slow as hell, but thats normal. I use it in a production environment and it works fine, much better than DosBox, at least for my particular needs.

The problem here, as I think most users didn't notice or care, is that, with this, also comes the ability to once again run the old 16BIT viruses from the DOS era. So, if you plan to do this wonderful trick, be aware it may come with the chance to infect your machine/network with some old nasties.

Comment: I am abstaining from voting on it because I cant decide if it answers the question.